# Cookies callback for expiration

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is that possible way to trigger JS callback when Cookies expires?

I want to pop up a alert when one of the cookies got expired.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes? I'd be moderately annoyed if a site pops up an alert just because a cookie expired (actually, I'd be annoyed if it pops up an alert for anything at all, its just terrible design).

Comment: @Gimby, no , say we store something in cookies and use that cookies to display information to user, and we want to let user know that information is expired/deleted when that cookies expires.

Comment: Well you lost me as a potential user. Because you use tracking cookies and you show alerts.

Comment: @Gimby, didn't get what you mean, can u describe more?

Comment: This should at least explain a little: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/106031/javascripts-prompt-confirm-and-alert-considered-old-fashioned/106039#106039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard API for it.

You could examine `document.cookies`, parse out the expiry dates from the cookies, compare them to the current time (via `Date()`) and then `setTimeout` on them.

Alternatively (and less efficiently), you could poll the server with XMLHttpRequest and return information about if a cookie was in the request or not and then alert based on that returned value.

Obviously, this won't work if a page on the site with the cookie is not being displayed at the time the cookie expires.

Comment: I think we can use setTimeout to achieve all the things